# Transferring GetBitmapBits() over the network, safe?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I'm doing `GetBitmapBits()` over an `HBITMAP` and storing the pixels in a plain `char*` buffer and sending that buffer over network.

The client is then "reconstructing" the bitmap using `SetBitmapBits()` in its window.

My question is pretty simple: Is there any probable or possible situation when reconstruction might not be possible? Maybe for the internal byte storage format of these pixel data?

Client and server are not guaranteed to use the same version of Windows. Server may use XP whereas the client may use Vista or Windows 7, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144850%28VS.85%29.aspx) itself mentions you should use GetDIBits / SetDIBits instead.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Chris' suggestion that you should use [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I can add that:

1. Since the documentation for either function does not have any explicit warnings about compatibility concerns, you can assume there aren't any -- indeed, if the memory representation of a DIB changed between versions, you can be sure many programs would take immediate offense.
2. Since all you are doing is push `char`s over the network, there cannot be any problems stemming from that due to possible different endianness between your source and target systems.

Comment: GetBitmapBits explicitly says that the format is device specific. It is thus going to depend on the current video mode selected in that device, and the actual device driver in use.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: That's why it is suggested to use `GetDIBits` instead; that one is device-independent as the name suggests.